# RPC Error: Methods Not Found

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, json-rpc, javascript, expanse

I am using the Expanse version of go-ethereum to play with Expanse.  I am exposing the RPC port over the 'net, and connecting to it using "geth attach" from another computer.  None of the commands that I am used to using at the console are working.  For example:

```
> admin.peers
ReferenceError: 'admin' is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

And the same problem happens using curl.

When I enter this:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"miner_start","params":[4],"id":74}' localhost:8545
```

I get this reply:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":74,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"The method miner_start does not exist/is not available"}}
```

I probably have a very simple option turned off but there are so many "rpc" this and thats that I am kind of getting lost.  Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the commands available at the console (`ipc`) are not available over rpc for security reasons. If you know your `rpc` connection cannot be accessed by anyone other than yourself, launch `geth` with the following flags to expose the additional APIs:

```
geth --rpc --rpcapi web3,eth,personal,miner,net,txpool
```

Add any additional APIs you need to the parameters of `--rpcapi`.

Comment: You should add admin for admin.peers to work.